# Transactional CDI bean: How to force transaction rollback

Tags: java, transactions

I have a @RequestScoped, @Transactional CDI bean injected in my REST interface:

```
@RequestScoped
@Transactional
public class myRestCall
{
    @Inject
    EntityHandlerService    ehs;        // contains @PersistenceContext

    try
    {
       // execute business logic, access DB via ehs (JPA / Hibernate)
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        // log exception
        // -> rollback transaction
    }
}
```

Now I like to have a try / catch around the call of the business logic that I can log the exception properly. But I need to rollback the transaction manually, unless I throw the exception again what I do not like. So how can I force the transasction rollback here? I know how to do it, if it would be a EJB: We could do

```
@Resource
private SessionContext ctx;
```

and then

```
ctx.setRollbackOnly();
```

in the `catch` close.

However, it **is not** an EJB and I cannot make an EJB out of it due to resource limits.

Comment: Did you ever got a way to achieve what you intended to do?

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer, you can add the @Resource TransactionSynchronizationRegistry and then call setRollbackOnly();

```
@RequestScoped
class MyBean {
    @Resource
    private TransactionSynchronizationRegistry reg;

    @Transactional
    void yourmethod()
    {
        try {
             // do stuff

        } catch (Exception e) {
             reg.setRollbackOnly();       
        }

    }
}
```

If you can't use @Resource,  you can lookup the trx resgistry with jndi:

java:comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry

Answer (score 0):

You can include a parameter rollbackOn="Exception.class" asociated to the @Transactional annotation.

But if yo do so, you must quit the "try-catch" block

Comment: According to the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html - it is actually `rollbackOn`.

Comment: @Wakachopo: What do you mean with *But if yo do so, you must **quit** the "try-catch" block*?

Comment: If you use a try-catch block into the method, the exception thrown in the try block will be handled in the catch block, and wil never be rollbacked. This can be useful if you do not want particular exceptions to cause a rollback, For example, if you catch a NullPointerException, this kind of exceptions will not cause a rollback, but any other type of Exception will. If an exception is catched, the @Transactional will not see the exception, cause it is not throwed.

Comment: @Wakachopo: I understand. But my question ask exactly this: I want to catch every throwable, do logging and manually force a rollback **and do not want to throw the exeption to the container**. Therefore, your answer does not answer the question and does not help!

Comment: You can catch the exception, log it, and then throw the same exception from the catch block. It will be logged and then rollbacked, as the exception manually thrown is never catched.

Comment: Dear Wakachopo. I know. But this is not the answer to the question. The question is how to **force** the rollback! If you read the question, you will see that I have written that I know that I could rethrow the exception.